# Parallel.ForEach is exited before it completes

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Well, I'm using Parallel ForEach to process a very big array of Colors (35M of indexers).

I'm using Partitioner.Create to do this with perfomance. But something unexpected is happening:

```
private Color32[] MainGeneration(Color32[] proccesed, Color32[] dupe, int width, int height)
{
    int i = 0;
    Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, totalIndexes), item =>
    {
        int x = i % width;
        int y = height - i / width - 1;

        dupe[i] = (UnityEngine.Color)MapIteration((Color)((Color)(UnityEngine.Color)proccesed[i]).Clone(), i, x, y)
        ++i;
        if (i % updateInterlockedEvery == 0)
        {
            ++currentIndex; //Interlocked.Increment(ref currentIndex);
        }
    });

    // If Parallel.ForEach is blocking, why this is outputting me 12 when total indexes value is 35.000.000?
    Debug.Log(i);
    return dupe;
}
```

As I wroted on the comment, why is this happening?

The expected behaviour of this, is to process a large image using parallelism, not only a small piece.

`processed` contains the full image.

`dupe` contains a empty array that will be completed on each iteration.

I do all this in the local scope to avoid heap problems.

Comment: why are you incrementing `i` in the body and ignoring `item`?

Comment: Instead of looking for Parallel.ForEach bugs, consider that you are modifying a *global variable* from multiple threads. The results will be random at best.

Comment: Your ++i isn't threadsafe.

Comment: Why are you using/modifying `i` at all? What's `totalIndexes`? `Parallel.ForEach` does a good job of partitioning the input according to the number of available cores. If you care about the index of an item, use a `Parallel.ForEach` overload that [passes the index to the item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_ForEach__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Action___0_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState_System_Int64__) along with it to `body`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want something like, [Fiddle Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9UtRMj)

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using UnityEngine;

public class Program
{       
    private void MainGeneration(
            Color32[] source,
            Color32[] target,
            int width,
            int height)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(source, true)
                .GetOrderableDynamicPartitions(), colorItem =>
        {
            var i = colorItem.Key;
            var color = colorItem.Value;
            var x = i % width;
            var y = height - i / width - 1;
            target[i] = this.Map(color, i, x, y);
        });
    }

    private Color32 Map(Color32 color, long i, long x, long y)
    {
        return color;   
    }                
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was so helpful. I have another two questions, why isn't my processing getting a perfomance improvement? (I'm reporting the same time as sequential processing). And, if I want to use less cpu, setting [ParallelOptions.MaxDegreesOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) is valid? Because, I don't want to block the entire CPU.

Comment: @z3nth10n perhaps there are better ways of doing this. Not very fresh memory, but sounds like your calculations could be done with a shader....

Comment: I would be so grateful if you explain this more in detail. Could you? Thanks! I'm processing [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1295599/order-points-from-array-based-on-8-connectivity-mo.html) using parallelization, maybe I don't see any perfomance improvements because I'm only returning a Color, not doing any complex calculation. I'm right?

Comment: @z3nth10n, as I said, i've been a long time away from this topic and it is a huge topic. In the "days of old", texture manipulation could be done through pixel shaders and vertices manipulation was done through vertex shaders, now I see terms like fragment shader and compute shader, and more. I am also not familiar with unity itself, my shader experience is fairly old and was directly DX/GL. You can start at: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/gentle-introduction-shaders .Once you have more direct questions, I am sure there are people here in a better capacity to help you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, I won't use this anyway, because, I output colors only as a debug solution. The real concern here is to get the shapes from a texture, I need to return a typed object, so I imagine that Shaders here can't do so much. Thanks anyway!

Comment: As you can see sequential is quickly than paralllel... https://dotnetfiddle.net/p0DyAI

Answer (score 2):

`++i;` is in fact shorthand for something like this:

```
  temp = i + 1;
  i = temp;
```

Luckily you are using int not long, so at least the `i = temp;` assignment is atomic, the explanation is easier :)

If two threads are both doing ++i; something like this can happen (only two threads considered for simplicity):

```
//Let's say i == 0
Thread 2 calculates i + 1 //== 1
Thread 1 calculates i + 1 //== 1
Thread 1 sets i = 1;
Thread 2 sets i = 1;
```

So here you would probably expect i to be 2, but in fact it is 1 by the end of this.

If you want to increment i in a threadsafe manner you can do:

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref i);
```

As pointed in your code for currentIndex which should be also calculated like this.

I see another issue with the code given the huge discrepancy in numbers. Exceptions that happen outside of the main thread are not reported to/on the main thread if the IsBackGround property of the thread is true. To guard against this, you should try/catch the inner block in the foreach to also count exceptions in a similar way.

Or even better, get a list of exceptions in a ConcurrentQueue/ConcurrentBag :

```
// Use ConcurrentQueue to enable safe enqueueing from multiple threads.
var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();

// Execute the complete loop and capture all exceptions.
Parallel.ForEach(data, d =>
{
    try
    {
        // Cause a few exceptions, but not too many.
        if (d < 3)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Value is {d}. Value must be greater than or equal to 3.");
        else
            Console.Write(d + " ");
    }
    // Store the exception and continue with the loop.                    
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptions.Enqueue(e);
    }
});
Console.WriteLine();

// Throw the exceptions here after the loop completes.
if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
```

(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops)

Comment: Wow, this snippet is very useful! Thanks for the suggestions!